# Python Error Handling concerning datetime and time

Tags: python, datetime

I have this variable called `pubdate` which is derived from rss feeds. Most of the time it's a time tuple which is what I want it to be, so there are no errors.

Sometimes it's a unicode string, that's where it gets annoying.

So far, I have this following code concerning `pubdate` when it is a unicode string:

```
if isinstance(pubdate, unicode):
    try:
        pubdate = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(pubdate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').timetuple()) # turn the string into a unix timestamp
    except ValueError:
        pubdate = re.sub(r'\w+,\s*', '', pubdate) # removes day words from string, i.e 'Mon', 'Tue', etc.
        pubdate = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(pubdate, '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S').timetuple()) # turn the string into a unix timestamp
```

But my problem is if the unicode string `pubdate` is in a different format from the one in the `except ValueError` clause it will raise another `ValueError`, what's the pythonic way to deal with multiple `ValueError` cases?

Comment: The `datetime` module can parse `Mon` as well. Post sample input/output if possible.

Comment: It's just a personal preference that I remove the Mon, Tue, etc.. An example input that would raise another `ValueError` would be `pubdate = 10/14/2015 11:11` because it doesn't have seconds. That's something that I can't control because it's derived from an rss feed. I'm just having trouble handling multiple ValueError exceptions that will occur due to how `pubdate` is formatted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are parsing date string from a Rss. Maybe you need some guess when parsing the date string. I recommend you to use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) instead of the datetime module.

`dateutil.parser` offers a generic date/time string parser which is able to parse most known formats to represent a date and/or time.

The prototype of this function is: `parse(timestr)`(you don't have to specify the format yourself).

**DEMO**

```
>>> parse("2003-09-25T10:49:41")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 49, 41)

>>> parse("2003-09-25T10:49")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 49)

>>> parse("2003-09-25T10")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 0)

>>> parse("2003-09-25")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 0, 0)

>>> parse("Sep 03", default=DEFAULT)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 3, 0, 0)
```

Fuzzy parsing:

```
>>> s = "Today is 25 of September of 2003, exactly " \
...     "at 10:49:41 with timezone -03:00."
>>> parse(s, fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 49, 41,
              tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -10800))
```

Comment: This pretty much eliminated my need of multiple try and except methods for unicode date strings. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could take the following approach:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time

pub_dates = ['2/5/2013 12:23:34', 'Monday 2 Jan 2013 12:23:34', 'mon 2 Jan 2013 12:23:34', '10/14/2015 11:11', '10 2015']

for pub_date in pub_dates:
    pubdate = 0     # value if all conversion attempts fail
    
    for date_format in ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', '%A %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M']:
        try:
            pubdate = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(pub_date, date_format).timetuple()) # turn the string into a unix timestamp
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
    
    print(f'{pubdate:<12}  {pub_date}')
```

Giving output as:

```
1367493814.0  2/5/2013 12:23:34
1357129414.0  Monday 2 Jan 2013 12:23:34
1357129414.0  mon 2 Jan 2013 12:23:34
1444817460.0  10/14/2015 11:11
0             10 2015
```