# Wait for valid DateTime reply in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command waits for a date and time string that's in the right format. I'm using the wait_for command with a check function but  It also checks if the date is somewhere in the future.
I want the bot to send a message to the user if the format is incorrect.Is there a better way to validate the string because currently it automatically throws an error if not correct.

````
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime 

    @commands.command(name='Due', brief="", description="Add an item that's due")
    @commands.cooldown(1, 2)
    async def add_due(self, ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.send("When is it due? (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS) \n NB: Time is optional")

        def check(m):
            if m.author == ctx.author:
                x = parse(m.content)
                return isinstance(x, datetime) and x > datetime.now()
            # send error message if not in correct format
        
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check,timeout=30)
        due = parse(msg.content)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should try with **Exception**s in python. It's super handy.

[Here is one solution for DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117704/python-error-handling-concerning-datetime-and-time)

[And exception statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)